Streamfunction and Potential Function in Complex Potential Theory
I am working on a university project involving the complex potential function, and I have the following question: Why was the streamfunction defined as the imaginary part of the complex potential, and the potential function as the real part of it?
Additionally, could you recommend any good literature on this topic?
Thanks in advance!
